# Parabola directrix formula

Tags: graphing-functions

[image: Bola]

Question 1:
I don't understand why (p+x)^2 = (MP)^2
Does it include positive and negative values?

Question 2:
Why is x + p = 0

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear from the picture that when the focus is $p$ units to the right of the origin and the directrix $p$ units to the left that the parabola lives in the right half plane, so $x \ge 0$. Then $p+x$ is the horizontal distance from the directrix to $M$.

The answer to your second question is that $x = -p$ is the equation of the vertical line through $(-p, 0)$. Since the line is vertical there's no $y$ in that equation.